# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^2}} $.

Tags: analysis, limits

I was trying to find the radius of convergence of the power series

$$\Sigma \frac{2^nz^n}{n^2}$$

and with the ratio test, found that the radius of convergence is $1 \over 2$.

However, I am practicing on finding limits and I would like to know how to proceed using the ratio test.

So I was trying to evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|\frac{2^nz^n}{n^2}|} = |2z| \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

From the ratio test I can see that the limit I want to solve for must go to $1$, and I can see that the form looks close to

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$$

which I know that converges to $1$.

How can I use this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use multiplication and division of limits.

Remember that if $a_n \ne 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^2 = a^2$$

Now just apply the case where $a_n = n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $a = 1$.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure this was ok. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler if you consider the logarithm:
$$
\log\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^2}}=-\frac{2\log n}{n}
$$
and it's a standard application of l'Hôpital's theorem showing that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{2\log n}{n}=0,
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^2}}=e^0=1.
$$

Comment: I really appreciate your help and it is easy, makes sense and legitimate. However, I am still not even doing derivatives, so I cannot use this rule, unfortunately ...